# Trying to understand why my script repeats

Tags: c

I am taking an online course with very little support. I am trying to follow instructions and write a script that takes input and draws two rectangles. Unfortunately, it just repeats infinitely, and I don't know what I'm missing. Any guidance would really help! Thank you so much for your help and time, this is my first post and I apologize for any formatting errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* 
 * Determines if coord is in range between
 * offset (INCLUSIVE) and offset + size (EXCLUSIVE)
 */
int isInRange(int coord, int offset, int size) {
  // if coord is in range, return 1
  if ((coord >= offset) && (coord < (offset + size))) {
      return 1;
    }
  // else, return 0
  else {
    return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}

/*
 * Determines if coord is at border of offset or
 * offset + size
 */
int isAtBorder(int coord, int offset, int size) {
  // if coord is equal to offest or offset + size
  if (coord == offset || (offset + size)) {
    return 1;
  }
  // return 1, else return 0
  else {
    return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}

void squares(int size1, int x_offset, int y_offset, int size2) {
  //compute the max of size1 and (x_offset + size2).  Call this w
  int w = (size1 + (x_offset + size2));
  //compute the max of size1 and (y_offset + size2).  Call this h
  int h = (size1 + (y_offset + size2));
  //count from 0 to h. Call the number you count with y
  for (int y = 0; y < h; h++) {
    //count from 0 to w. Call the number you count with x
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      //check if  EITHER
      //    ((x is between x_offset  and x_offset +size2) AND
      if (((isInRange(x, x_offset, size2) == 1) &&
      //     y is equal to either y_offset OR y_offset + size2 - 1)
       (isAtBorder(y, y_offset, size2 - 1) == 1))
      //  OR
      ||
      //    ((y is between y_offset and y_offset + size2) AND
      ((isInRange(y, y_offset, size2) == 1) &&
      //     x is equal to either x_offset OR x_offset + size2 -1)
       (isAtBorder(x, x_offset, size2-1)))) {
      // if so, print a *
    printf ("*");
      }

      //if not,
      // check if EITHER
      //    x is less than size1 AND (y is either 0 or size1-1)
      else {
    if (((x < size1) && (isAtBorder(y, 0, size1 - 1) == 1))
      // OR
           ||
      //    y is less than size1 AND (x is either 0 or size1-1)
           ((y < size1) && (isAtBorder(x, 0, size1 - 1) == 1))) {
      //if so, print a #
    printf ("#");
      }
      //else print a space
    else {
     printf (" ");
    }
      }
    }
    //when you finish counting x from 0 to w,
    //print a newline
    printf ("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, have you debugged the code? The usual way is to run the code in a debugger. It will tell you what the code is doing and and you can examine the state to find out why it is in a loop.

Comment: You've got a couple typos. The first is `|| (offset + size)` in `isAtBorder()`, and the second is `h++` in the `for` loop in `squares()`.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is, I suppose, in your squares function. Check out your for loop in this snippet:

```
for (int y = 0; y < h; h++) {
    //count from 0 to w. Call the number you count with x
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
```

In the first loop you're incrementing h, not y. Your "y" variable always stays at value which is equal 0, thus it won't finish this loop, since it will ALWAYS be smaller than "h" variable, unless "h" is less or equal than 0. You probably were aiming to increment "y" variable, not h.

After that, please check out your isAtBorder function. The "or" logical operator:

```
int isAtBorder(int coord, int offset, int size) {
  // if coord is equal to offest or offset + size
  if (coord == offset || (offset + size)) {
    return 1;
  }
  // return 1, else return 0
  else {
    return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

in the if statement is always true, so basically this function always returns 1.